# Map with one value as key and another as list if same key has multiple appearances in java

Tags: java, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to form and iterate a map which will have duplicates keys in it and arraylist as values . I have tried following but its not working as I expected. Assume

```
value1="Ramu" 
value2="1";
value3="2";
value1="Ramu"
value2="3";
value3="4";
value1="John"
value2="1"
value3="2"
```

When I am iterating the map , I should get value 1,2,3,4 for key Ramu and 1,2 for key John
Here is my piece of code

```
SQL="select value1,value2,value from student where student="Ramu"";
Bean bean;
ArrayList<Bean> beanList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
Map<String,ArrayList<Bean>> holder=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Bean>>();
pst = null;
rs = null;
try {
           pst = conn.createStatement();
            rs = pst.executeQuery(SQL);
 while (rs.next()) {                    
                String value1=rs.getString("value1");

                bean = new Bean();                
                bean.setvalue2(rs.getString("value2"));
                bean.setvalue3(rs.getString("value3"));
                beanList.add(bean);
               holder.put(value1, beanList);

            }
```

Comment: Duplicate keys are not posible in Java's maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always use the same `beanList`. You need to create a new list whenever you insert a new entry in the map.

```
String value1=rs.getString("value1");

bean = new Bean();                
bean.setvalue2(rs.getString("value2"));
bean.setvalue3(rs.getString("value3"));

beanList = holder.containsKey(value1) ? holder.get(value1) : new ArrayList<Bean>();
beanList.add(bean);
holder.put(value1, beanList);
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the purpose of maps is that you have a **unique** key which points to a value. Keys cannot be duplicated, it wouldn't make any sense and inserting a value with a key that is already present in the map only rewrites the previous value.

So in your case your keys should be "Ramu" and "John" and then you would have mapping:

- Ramu -> List(1,2,3,4)
- John -> List(1,2)

Comment: Please let me knwo how to avoid inserting same value as key multiple times @TTT

Comment: if (map.get(yourKey) == null) //key hasnt been used

Comment: @dbrown93 : not the best option, I would prefer containsKey ...  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)